# Is there any way to Capitalize all elements via xStream?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I am using xStream to format my XML.

```
<Messages>
  <message>
    <header>
      <origin>
        <Device>
          <deviceId>deviceId</deviceId>
        </Device>
```

of course I can do this:

```
xstream.alias("Messages", Messages.class);
xstream.alias("Message", Message.class);
xstream.addImplicitCollection(Messages.class, "message", "Message", Message.class);
xstream.aliasField("Header", Message.class, "header");
xstream.aliasField("Origin", Header.class, "origin");
```

Is there some kind of global setting to upper case all elements?

Comment: Annotate the classes and fields with [`@XStreamAlias`](http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html#Aliasing).

Comment: Note: XML element names are case-sensitive and should not be changed arbitrarily for aesthetics:  `<Message/>` is a different element than `<message/>`.

Comment: Have you find a solution for this ? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I did not find a solution.